# Does removing ID from URL improve SEO?

Tags: seo, url, identifier

My URLs are currently looking like

```
example.com/products/123/product-name
```

where *123* is the product ID.

I can make them like

```
example.com/products/product-name
```

by saving the URL as unique field in the database, but does it make a real difference for SEO, and is it worth the effort?

I see Webmasters SE (this question URL) uses ID in its URL, but I guess that's because there are a lot of questions with the same title. I don't have a lot of products with the same title, but some have.

Comment: Sorry but there is already dozens of questions and answers regarding the use of Product ID SEO and SEF URLS on Pro Webmasters already. Please see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo+url for even more related questions and answers.

Comment: I guess you found the page i added to the edit but the answer is not about seo else i would really want to get the link to the specific page, also i alrady have the slug friendly title i only remove id i dont add anything like in most questions.

Comment: @bybe that answer has nothing to do with seo only with what looks nice for the visitor and in bookmarks. not seo (search engine optimization)

Comment: As previously said there are lots of questions and answers on Pro Webmasters in the relation of creating SEO URLS. The linked question is relevant but just because you can't find an answer doesn't necessary merit creating a new question, Stack Exchange questions and answers can be improved at anytime even after the question has been accepted.

Comment: @bybye I agree but can you give me a link i am mostly interesting in the explanation. I would really appreciate if you can post a link to the question with an answer as i asked the question as you flagged this question as duplicate.

Comment: In the linked question if you look in the answer `The numerical ID-based URL doesn't give any indication about the type of content that is on the page.` states the obvious. In other words unless your using a external known product code such as a SKU, UPC, MPN, EAN, ISBN, ASIN then it would be no value to search engines.

Comment: Yes but because i already use slug for title I am only interested if removing something will improve SEO, I am not gone add ID to the url I will remove it if it is worth the effort.

Comment: Removing it will be little to no gain, words in URL can be come diluted but normally only with other words, no ID's. All big companies with lots of urls use numbers+product (Ebay, Amazon, Stack Exchange and so on..)

Comment: Removing the ID will make no difference at all. It has to do with parsing the URI and weighing keywords. Your ID will basically have no weight therefore it will not dilute the URI as a result since it really will not count as a keyword.